# How to compose a react parent component where the children are placed at different locations

Tags: reactjs, components

So I want to implement a component that is used like this:

```
<Parent>
  <Child1 childName="Billy" />
  <Child2 childName="Bob" />
</Parent>
```

The implementation of the `Parent` component should be something like this:

```
const Parent = (props: {
    Child1: React.ReactNode;
    Child2: React.ReactNode;
  }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <div>This is Title</div>
        {props.Child1}

        <div>This is another component</div>
        {props.Child2}
      </>
    );
  };
```

The problem here is, this doesn't work in react as it would in .Net Blazor or any other framework that supports it.

I understand the following:

- I can use the `children` props in react but this would only allow me to render all the children at the same location which I am trying to avoid.
- I can just go ahead and assign the various child components as property values in the form of `<Parent child1={<SomeChild/>} />`. But I feel this goes against the aesthetics of my code base.

Summing it all up, I just want an alternative way to implement this instead of using the `prop-value assignment` or using the `children` props.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing both components as `children` prop. You can access them like `props.children`

```
  const Parent = ({children}: {
    children: ReactNode
  }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <div>This is Title</div>
        {children[0]}

        <div>This is another component</div>
        {children[1]}
      </>
    );
  };
```

Also there is an object called `Children` that you can import from react, that has some methods to work with children
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/08/react-children-iteration-methods/

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this! And the link added has been greatly helpful.